# VBA - Combo Box scroll down bar broken

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a client management utility for my workplace, with various note entry / viewer system + dropdown for convenience and efficiency.

Right now I am having an issue where on a userform, after clicking a combobox, the user cannot click on the scroll bar to drag down. They can click the arrow to scroll down, but not the bar itself for faster scrolling.

What is weird is that the file I sent, "7.8", was a direct copy of my file but with my colleagues clients info inserted. On my version, made 5 minutes before, the click on scroll down bar works perfectly. I took screenshots of the combo box properties and couldn't find what if anything had changed.

This also occurs on a userform which I made ZERO changes to today, again not working on his but working on mine. Are there common issues that can occur when having multiple workbooks open? All of my userform code targets this workbook &  identifties the sheet by codename. All of the other features are working, including much more complex things then whether or not a scroll bar is draggable...

a bit puzzled. Anyone have any ideas?

So I put an example of the code below: I successfully use the same code at several points with small shifts to identify if a given account owner is selected, and if so, load the matching clients, and if a client is selected, to load the timestamp for a note.

What is weird is that the code identified has been the exact opposite of reproducible. I had workbook 7.8, copy-pasted it, changed the client data (which in no way affected the underlying code), and sent to my colleague, whose then experience of the userforms was that the scroll bars can have the button down click but not drag on the bar itself. The only thing I can think of is somehow if having multiple workbooks caused an issue, but out of all of the > 1000 lines of code, there isnt even a single line of code of mine which does anything to the scroll bar. And somehow in the 5 minutes from emailing to him, the scroll bar lost partial functionality?

```
 Sub noteOwnerClients()

    Dim wsFound As Worksheet
  Dim mainBook As Workbook
Set mainBook = ThisWorkbook
Dim rangeFinder As Range
Dim rangeInt As Integer
Dim rangePull As String
Dim selectedString As String

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If StrComp(ws.CodeName, "sheetDatabase", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        Set wsFound = ws
    End If
Next ws

noteClientCombo.Clear

selectedString = noteOwnerCombo.Text

    If selectedString <> "" Then
        rangeInt = 2
            For Each rangeFinder In wsFound.Range("E2:E200")
                    If selectedString = rangeFinder.Value Then
                        rangePull = "A" & rangeInt
                        noteClientCombo.AddItem wsFound.Range(rangePull)
                    End If
                rangeInt = rangeInt + 1
            Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: From a regular property standpoint I can't think of anything that would make that behaviour happen. How are the combo boxes created and populated on the userform?

Comment: Your odds of getting a useful answer go up dramatically when the issue is reproducible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you share the workbook possibly, or the code and some sample data?